# Tidy moving SVG <title> tag into html <head> (Notepad++)

Tags: html, svg, notepad++, tidy

I'm using Tidy2 via Notepad++ to clean up my HTML.  I've noticed that it's moving any [SVG `<title>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title) to the HTML's `<head>` (at first I thought they were just getting removed).  For example, a document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The page's title</title>
</head>
<body>    
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 9 9">
      <title>The SVG's title</title>
      <polygon points="3,0 0.5,0 0,0 0,0.5 0,3 0.5,3 0.5,0.5 3,0.5  "/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

gets converted to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39">
    <title>
      The page's title
    </title>
    <title>
      The SVG's title
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewbox="0 0 9 9">
      <polygon points="3,0 0.5,0 0,0 0,0.5 0,3 0.5,3 0.5,0.5 3,0.5">
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried using `output-html: yes`, `output-xml: yes`, or `output-xhtml: yes` (as well as none of those), but they all move it.  I also tried `show-body-only: yes`, but that just removed the `<title>` altogether.  **Is there a way to prevent this?** I didn't see related options on the Quick Reference or any solutions when searching here and Google.

Here is my config file at the moment:

```
indent: yes
indent-spaces: 2
wrap: 0
clean: no
markup: yes
vertical-space: yes
output-html: yes
preserve-entities: yes
quote-marks: no
new-inline-tags: title
new-blocklevel-tags: svg, polygon, title
new-empty-tags: polygon
```

Comment: looks like there's lots of problems, polygon not closed, viewBox lowercased, xmlns not removed. Perhaps you should look for another tool.

Comment: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/70

Comment: Hadn't even noticed the other things (though I believe the non-closed polygon is my fault because of one my configuration settings). Looks like there is also an existing issue for the viewBox problem: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/365 Looks like the suggested workaround there (`input-xml: yes`) won't work for my not-quite-xml HTML. I think I will open a new issue. Thanks, @RobertLongson.

Comment: Issue filed: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/419

Comment: Note that the "viewbox" attribute is not a problem. Since HTML is case-insensitive, the browser's parser will [adjust the attribute](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#adjust-svg-attributes) for you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was an issue with Tidy2 on Notepad++ being out of date.  See the related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/419

The workaround was provided Geoff McLane, who made a [fork of Tidy2](https://github.com/geoffmcl/NppTidy2), providing a new version of the Tiny2.dll.  Fixing this on my local machine required

1. going to the [page for the new Tidy2.dll](https://github.com/geoffmcl/NppTidy2/releases/tag/5.3.1),
2. downloading/opening the ZIP (which includes a reference of the configuration options as well some sample config files),
3. moving the Tiny2.dll file to the Notepad++/plugins directory (see note below),
4. closing and reopening Notepad++,

and the problem I was having in my question was no longer a problem.

(Note: I originally changed the old Tidy2.dll to OldTidy2.dll and left it in Notepad++/plugins, but when I restarted Notepad++, it was still behaving the same.  Things worked when I removed the old Tidy2.dll completely, then close/restart.)